# In Pandas, how to replace list elements in Series?

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I have a following series and would like to replace `a1` with `a`, `b1` with `b` and `c1` with `c`.

```
data = pd.Series([['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['b1', 'a1', 'c1'], ['c1', 'a1' ,'b1']])

Out[132]: 
0    [a1, b1, c1]
1    [b1, a1, c1]
2    [c1, a1, b1]
dtype: object
```

The expected results is as below.

```
0    [a, b, c]
1    [b, a, c]
2    [c, a, b]
dtype: object
```

The following code does what I am trying to do, but it does not seem to be a nice way to do.

```
for i, s in enumerate(data):
    temp = ['a' if x == 'a1' else x for x in s]
    temp = ['b' if x == 'b1' else x for x in temp]
    temp = ['c' if x == 'c1' else x for x in temp]
    data.iloc[i] = temp
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I assume pandas have a built-in function for this.

I tried it with `replace`, but it does not help.

```
data.replace['a1', 'a']
data.replace['b1', 'c']
data.replace['c1', 'c']
```

Thank you for any comment in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dictionary for replace and use list comprehension with `get` - second parameter `y` is if not exist key get original:

```
d = {'a1':'a', 'b1':'b', 'c1':'c'}

data = data.apply(lambda x: [d.get(y,y) for y in x])
#alternative solution
#data = data.map(lambda x: [d.get(y,y) for y in x])
print (data)
0    [a, b, c]
1    [b, a, c]
2    [c, a, b]
dtype: object
```

Or:

```
data = pd.Series([[d.get(y,y) for y in x] for x in data], index=data.index)
```

If performance not important:

```
data = data.explode().replace(d).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print (data)
0    [a, b, c]
1    [b, a, c]
2    [c, a, b]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. In your first solution, I am wondering if it is more relevant to use 'map' instead of 'apply' because  it is element wise. For example, data.map(lambda x: [d.get(y,y) for y in x]). I am learning about 'map' and 'apply', which is confusing. So I am wondering which one is more efficient.

Comment: @david78 - both working similar, you can use `map`

Comment: For some reason, my last comment that thanks to you is deleted. Once again, thank you so much for the great help :)